# Python JSON Decoding With Asynchat Cannot Catch ValueError Exception

Tags: json, python-2.7, sockets, server, asyncore

I can't seem to catch an exception when using json.loads even though I specifically call it out. I largely see this when trying to stress my server with lots of client connection sending data very quickly. See my error below:

(I've replaced my IP address with X's in the error code)

> EX:  Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 49 (char 48) Data:
>   '{"ap-hdop":0.55,"rtcmin":"38","ap-latdec":3.134,"a' error: uncaptured
>   python exception, closing channel
>    (:Unterminated string
>   starting at: line 1 column 49 (char 48)
>   [//faraday_server_handler.py|collect_incoming_data|34]
>   [/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py|loads|338]
>   [/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py|decode|366]
>   [/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py|raw_decode|382])

I understand this that the code fails because I simply miss a double quotes on the line:

'{"ap-hdop":0.55,"rtcmin":"38","ap-latdec":3.134,"a'

This line is usually a LOT longer so that "a.... was supposed to keep going and complete it's quotes.

Here's my relevant code:

```
def collect_incoming_data(self, data):
    """Read an incoming message from the client, place JSON message data into buffer"""
    #self.logger.debug('collect_fing_data() -> (%d bytes)\n"""%s"""', len(data), data)
    try:
        loaded_data = json.loads(data)

    except ValueError, ex:
        self.handle_error()
        type,value,traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print type
        #print "Collect Incoming Data: " . time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.gmtime())
        print "EX: ", ex
        print "Data: ",repr(data)
```

Any ideas? I scoured the internet to see if I can find this issue, but I appear to be setting up to capture the exception which everyone else having this issue with loads seems to suggest to do.

EDIT 3/1/2016 - Evening

Commenting out my exception handle_error() let me see more of the error:

```
except ValueError, ex:
    self.handle_error()
    type,value,traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print type
    #print "Collect Incoming Data: " . time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.gmtime())
    print "EX: ", ex
    print "Data: ",repr(data)
```

Below is my new error, I've commented out personal data. It's apparent that the issue I really have now is in-fact the unterminated string

> EX:  Unterminated string starting at:
>   line 1 column 49 (char 48) Data: 
>   '{"ap-hdop":0.55,"rtcmin":"31","ap-latdec":XX.XXX,"a'  EX:  No JSON object could be decoded Data: 
>   'p-latdeg":34,"adc6":2006,"adc7":2007,"adc4":2004,"adc5":2005,"adc2":2002,"adc3":2003,"adc0":2000,"adc1":2001,"gpio-0":30,"gpio-1":50,"gpio-2":70,"speed":5.0,"adc8":2008,"rtcday":"01","longdeg":118,"longdec":XX.XXX,"altitude":31.0,"ap-speed":0.0,"ap-pdop":0.77,"lat-dir":"N","long-dir":"W","hdop":0.01,"ap-rf":0,"alt-units":"M","rtcdow":"2","callsign":"XXXXX","ap-callsign":"XXXXX","id":1,"ap-id":1,"rtcyear":"2016","rtcmon":"03","ap-vdop":0.66,"ap-lat-dir":"N","vdop":0.02,"rtchour":"22","latdec":XX.XXX,"latdeg":34,"ap-longdeg":118,"ap-longdec":XX.XXX,"rtcsec":"15","ap-altitude":86.0,"ap-long-dir":"W","pdop":0.01,"ap-alt-units":"M","faraday-port":0}'

Comment: if you comment out `self.handle_error()` does it work as expected? the print statements in the except block are definitely executing from looking at the output but I think `handle_error` was designed to handle errors that are unhandled otherwise.

Comment: Oh interesting @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that actually did allow me to see more of the issue, I've edited the original question with an update! I haven't fully tested it to see if the original error went completely away but I think this is a large step to solving the original problem.

Secondary problem is why is my data splitting up like that even with terminators "\r\n" used...

Comment: hold up.... you are getting the `EX:` message multiple times! You are receiving the json data in chunks and each part is invalid on it's own!

Answer (score 0):

OK my original question was answered which was "Why am I not catching the ValueError exception even though I am providing code to do just that?"

@tadhg McDonald-jensen was correct with his comment to remove my call to handle_error().

I still have some other issues but they are a different question. Thanks!